# couchbase lite Invalid database name

Tags: java, couchbase-lite

```
try {
    uploadDone = manager.getDatabase("uploadDone");
    uploadDone.compact();
} catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Method threw `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` exception.
Invalid database name: **uploadDone**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name must consist only of lowercase ASCII letters, digits, and the special characters `_$()+-/`. It must also be less than 240 bytes and start with a lower case letter.